# Parsing/converting ISO 8601 datetime fields using pandas

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime field in a Pandas dataframe that becomes problematic when using ArcGIS Pro to load data from a csv to a table on ArcSDE.  The field in Pandas looks like this:

```
2007-02-01T05:00:00.0000000+00:00
```

but the output in field in ArcGIS Pro reads the datetime column as 12/30/1899 throughout the entire dataset.

I tried using a pandas script to parse the field:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(['Time'], 
                        format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

but I'm receiving:

> ValueError: time data Time doesn't match format specified

I simply want the field in an acceptable format to load into an ArcSDE table.

**Update:**

The suggested change worked:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f", errors = 'coerce')
```

The result in Pandas is this:

```
Time    
2007-02-01 05:00:00+00:00
```

but after using the append tool in ArcGIS Pro, the time field defaults to:

```
12/30/1899
```

Answer (score 5):

A working sample

```py
import pandas as pd
 
data = [{'mydate': '2007-02-01T05:00:00.0000000+00:00', 'b': 2, 'c':3},
        {'mydate': '2007-02-01T05:00:00.0000000+00:00', 'b': 20, 'c': 30}]
 
# Creates DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Below line commented to adopt simpler alternative
# df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
# Simplified version due to Mike T comment
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'])
```

Your issue is that you use

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(['Time'], 
                        format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

instead of

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], 
                        format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

The difference is in `pd.to_datetime(['Time']` vs `pd.to_datetime(df['Time']`

As stated by Mike T in comment, a simplified version can be
`df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])`

Although you are using ArcGIS Pro, the issue is unrelated to geospatial. In this case, it's better to post on http://stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: furthermore ISO formats are automatically detected, so `pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])` works fine.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: @ThomasG77  thank you, that did work in parsing the field but the field still read 12/30/1899 after appending the data to a table